# Hexadecimal to decimal in windbg

Tags: hex, decimal, windbg

It looks like the default for WinDbg is to display ints in decimal and unsigned ints in hexadecimal.
Is there a way to show all in decimal?

I tried using the `n` command [mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It gives me syntax error though:

```
:086> n[10]
      ^ Syntax error in 'n[10]'
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are using square brackets when you shouldn't. On the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), those square brackets are there to show that the radix argument is optional.

When the argument is left off, the current radix is displayed to you.

```
0:000> n
base is 10
```

When you provide the argument (with no square brackets) the current radix is changed and echoed back to you.

```
0:000> n 16
base is 16
```

A commonly used trick once the base is set is to use the `?` ([Evaluate Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) command to convert numbers to the new base (in this example, base 16).

```
0:000> ? 0n10
Evaluate expression: 10 = 0000000a

0:000> ? 0y11
Evaluate expression: 11 = 00000003
```

To convert from hex (base 16) back to decimal:

```
0:000> ? a
Evaluate expression: 10 = 0000000a
```

Remember that once the base is set, both input and output are affected meaning that when you want to enter a number that isn't is the current base, you will need to specify the base as was done above in the final example. Further reading on how numbers are handled in the MASM-like syntax is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552157%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But back to your original question...

Yes, `n 10` should be enough to force numbers to be displayed in decimal. If for some reason there is a problem, you can always use the `?` command as shown above to perform the conversion.

Comment: Yep, I just misunderstood the [] as to be part of the command not just to indicate that it is optional argument.

Answer (score 2):

Extended article describing how WinDbg evaluates expressions (including details on the impact of the n command) available here:

https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=540

Answer (score 0):

try using the command:-

.enable_long_status 0